# How to call PUT method in Fiddler

Tags: wcf, fiddler

I created a PUT WCF service to update my database. How do I call this service in fiddler to test if it working properly.

I did try the URL in Fiddler and it gave me 404!

Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the request builder there is a drop down. By default it shows "GET" and it allows you to select the HTTP method that you wish to use. Change this to "PUT" and you should be done.

You might also want to take a look at this...

[Doing a HTTP PUT from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856996/doing-a-http-put-from-a-browser)

... and investigate the use of the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

You should also read this...

**Use Fiddler to Test RESTful WCF Services**
http://www.keyvan.ms/use-fiddler-to-test-restful-wcf-services

Comment: is there anything I should add in request headers? Like I need to pass some parameters how do I do it?

Comment: Do you have a real client that calls this API? If so, my suggestion would be that you should use Fiddler to watch a real HTTP request and then reuse it (edit it, save it as a VS.NET MSTest WebTest or whatever).

Comment: Generally a PUT is very much like a POST, so it usually has a body. Fiddler allows you to supply that body. That said, check out the url I've just added to my answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "HTTP Error 403.1 - Forbidden: Execute access is denied." Do you have any idea?

Comment: Any chance you're seeing this issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946951/iis-http-error-403-1-forbidden-execute-access-is-denied

Comment: No that's fine, I should have use POST instead of PUT. It's all good, thank you for your help.